# Bottom half of terminal window doesn't get used

Tags: terminal

This keeps happening on a Macbook Pro running High Sierra. Upon a new terminal window, the cursor will go to the bottom of the screen as expected as you press enter. However, it often will stop half way as shown below. This seems to happen when I SSH in and out. Any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: what does `echo $LINES` show the `LINES` variable as set to?

Comment: @thrig it's outputting `51` regardless of where the cursor is.

Comment: does it change if you resize the terminal to some other number of lines?

Comment: Yeah, vertical adjustment changes the output.